# Very simple notation question

Tags: notation, terminology

What notation is it called when a number is represented as a series of additions, for example:

124 = 100 + 20 + 4

This is a very simple question obviously but I don't remember what it's called! Thanks.

EDIT:

The reason I ask this question is for programming reasons. I want to take a value, such as 124, and create a list of variables (100, 20, 4) from it, so I wanted to know what that operation/ notation or whatever was called. I hope this helps you narrow down the possible correct ideas.

Comment: This is known as Sigma notation

Comment: Or perhaps you simply mean 'decomposition'.

Comment: Are you talking only about "base $10$ decomposition," or are you including, say, $11=1+2+3+5$?

Comment: I am not including expressions like 11 = 1 + 2 + 3 + 5.

Comment: Are you referring to [positional notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positional_notation) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing the way you wrote it, I thought of basis. A natural number $a$, written in base $b$ (also natural), is denoted by: $$a =(a_na_{n-1}\ldots a_1 a_0)_b = a_nb^n + a_{n - 1}b^{n-1} + \ldots a_1b + a_0$$

where $0 \leq a_i < b$. For example, when we write stuff like $124$ or $1675$ or $223$, we actually mean $$(124)_{10} = 1 \times 10^2 + 2 \times 10 + 4$$
In computer science, people often use base $2$, for example, consider the number $12 = (12)_{10} $. We have $(12)_{10} = (1100)_2 = 1 \times 2^3 + 1 \times 2^2 + 0 \times 2 + 0 = 12$.

If we have a base greater than $10$, we start using letters to represent the new algarisms. For example, in base $12$, we let $a = 11$ and $b = 12$, and we get numbers like $(a43b)_{12}, (bb214a4)_{12}$, etc.

Comment: That's how I interpreted the question, too. +1

Comment: This is not what I meant at all. I will edit the post.

Comment: @Dingus, If you mean, as another example, $267$ would be $(200, 60, 7)$, then note that $2\times 10^2 + 6\times 10^1 + 7\times 10^0 = 200 + 60 + 7$, then this is indeed what Ivo is referring to: "base 10 decomposition" perhaps you can call it. If you mean, on the other hand, that $(200, 6, 1)$ would also work for representing $267$, then the word you want is "partition".

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care what order the terms come in, it is a [partition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory))  If you do care, it is a [composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics))